# Display of content does too wide for screen

Tags: content-width

On my 15.5" laptop, my website content width is displayed across-- off the screen. Maybe caused by PHP update last week. Noticed first on preview of new post, then when published. Old posts fit properly and when new post is viewed on a smaller screen laptop, the content fits the width as usual. What do I need to change to have content fit within the width of the screen?

Comment: DId the CSS for your theme update?

Comment: How do I determine this? Sorry, I'm a novice.

Comment: Usually it happens when your theme gets an update and you click the update button. Past that, you'd have to manually modify the CSS file yourself, which I assume you didn't do.

Comment: I don't think there's been a theme update. I have tried to modify the CSS file, changing the content maximum width from 100% to 69%. That did nothing. Any ideas of what else to change?